# Android AlertDialog, don't dismiss on key press, but on touch

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-alertdialog

I've found solutions on cancelling the dismissing of an AlertDialog when a button of the dialog is touched or a key pressed on the keyboard. However, I only want to cancel the dismissing if a **key** has been pressed, **touching** the buttons should still work.

E.g., how to keep an AlertDialog open if a key has been pressed, but keep the button touching functional?

Since I'm using Xamarin, here's my C# code so far, but real Java solutions are accepted too since they're easy to translate:

Building the dialog:

```
AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .SetTitle("blabla")
    .SetMessage("more bla")
    .SetPositiveButton("OK", (sender2, e2) => {
        // Do something
        SetResult(Result.Ok, oIntent);
        Finish(); })
    .SetNegativeButton("Cancel", (sender2, e2) => { })
    .Create();
dialog.SetOnShowListener(new AlertDialogShowListener(dialog));
dialog.Show();
```

And the implementation of the interfaces:

```
private class AlertDialogShowListener : Java.Lang.Object, IDialogInterfaceOnShowListener {
    private AlertDialog _dialog;

    internal AlertDialogShowListener(AlertDialog dialog) {
        _dialog = dialog;
    }

    public void OnShow(IDialogInterface dialog) {
        Button b = dialog.GetButton((int)DialogButtonType.Positive);
        b.SetOnClickListener(new ButtonOnClickListener());
        b = dialog.GetButton((int)DialogButtonType.Negative);
        b.SetOnClickListener(new ButtonOnClickListener());
    }
}

private class ButtonOnClickListener : Java.Lang.Object, View.IOnClickListener {
    public void OnClick(View v) {
        // How to NOT dismiss if a _key_ has been pressed?
    }
}
```

(PS: I know there's an easier way to write code like this in Xamarin by attaching the Click event, but I thought it's easier for Java professionals to follow it this way with the OnShow and OnClick listeners.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer!

After showing the alert dialog, get the buttons and override their onKeyPress method, so these don't call dismiss on the alert dialog.

In C# it looks like this:

```
AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .SetTitle("blabla")
    .SetMessage("blablabla")
    .SetPositiveButton("OK", (sender, e) => {
        SetResult(Result.Ok, oIntent);
        Finish();
    })
    .SetNegativeButton("Cancel", (sender, e) => { })
    .Show(); // Important, or GetButton() will return null

// Now disable the default dismissing actions on key presses.
dialog.GetButton((int)DialogButtonType.Positive).KeyPress += (sender, e) => { };
dialog.GetButton((int)DialogButtonType.Negative).KeyPress += (sender, e) => { };
```